# How can I check the OpenCL version on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, opencl

How can I check the [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) version on Microsoft Windows 7 (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate) with an [Nvidia GeForce GTX 660M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_series)?

---

I uunsuccessfully tried:

1. Run -> `dxdiag`: doesn't show my GTX660M (I tried looking at all three "display" tabs)

   [image]
2. Start → Control Panel → Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Device Manager -> Display Adapter ->  Right-click on GPU -> Properties: doesn't show the OpenCL version (I don't think that the file version is the OpenCL version?).

   [image]
3. [GPU-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU-Z) doesn't show the OpenCL version:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 660M supports OpenCL 1.2, as stated [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-660m.c345). Keeping your graphics drivers up to date should ensure you have all the runtimes you need. If you need help installing the SDK, that's a different question.

If you need a software tool to check on your OS, you can use [Geeks3D GPU Caps Viewer](https://www.geeks3d.com/20200602/gpu-caps-viewer-1-45-0-released/). The OpenCL tab will show you which version your hardware supports.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how can I check the OpenCL version on Windows 7?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I found one so I've updated the answer

Comment: NVidia say OpenCL 1.1 - [Google cached page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hCeaWdLo1GUJ:https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/geforce-gtx-660m/specifications/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=safari)